# How do you wire up the OV3640 camera module?

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, camera

I've been wanting to do a project with this module in mind and have found some resources on it (mainly arducam) but I have no idea how to connect it to a micro controller.

The data sheets show that it has an I2C connection but there are also 9 data wires which seem to have some sort of purpose?

If someone could tell me or point me in the right direction I would be very happy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The i2C interface is just to configure the image sensor's parameters. The actual image data is blasted out the parallel camera interface (called CAMIF), which consists of an 8 to 12 bit parallel data bus, plus horizontal and vertical sync signals and a pixel clock. The pixel clock tends to run at 50-100 MHz depending on resolution and framerate, so your microcontroller will need to have a hardware CAMIF module to handle the timing. Many high-end Cortex-M4 and Cortex-A processors from ST, Freescale, and TI have the hardware necessary for this. Obviously, an FPGA/CPLD could also perform this functionality.

You'll also need quite a bit of free memory to hold the frame(s) you grab from the image sensor -- a 2048 X 1536 image, in RGB888, will require ~9.6 megabytes.

Comment: Tipo: 2048*1536*3 = ~9MB, RGB888 uses 24bits or 3 bytes per pixel + some meta information

Comment: Thanks, updated!

Answer (score 1):

This won't help you much but I remember looking at that particular sensor a year or so ago and being put off rather by the data rate. It hurls 3 million pixels or so at you at 50+MHz. I'd no idea where to even put that data or how to keep up. You are into the area of using an FPGA or XMOS processor and a pile of RAM.

Having looked at the Arducam project you mention, I see that's exactly what they are doing. If that's what you are asking - "how do I use the arducam module with a microcontroller" then the answer appears to be "with an SPI interface for the data and I2C for the control". Looks very nice actually!

Edit: Without looking at it in too much detail, I assume the Arduino is being used for control only. You'd need an actual computer like a Raspberry Pi to do something with that much data.